# importing chart packages in jupyter lab notebook

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm trying to generate a chart in online jupyter lab notebook and it is not allowing by throwing errors.  Is it possible to do it there?

Thanks

[Updated the code and error]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
```

leads to the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import plotly.express as px

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

Comment: Yes, Just import the package what you want to use.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import plotly.express as px

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

@MOLLY getting the above error, what i need to do correct?

Comment: You probably do not have plotly installed in the environment from which Jupyter server is run. You could run `!pip install plotly` from your notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use package in jupyter notebook,
you should

1. install package by this line

`!pip install package-name`

then add new block to write code

2. import it in code

`import package-name`

(for someone if finding this question)